# How to turn a sorted array into a regulrar array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I sorted an array in PHP and got this as a result: (the numbers represent how often the word was found in that array)

```
Array
(
    [photo] => 9
    [photography] => 6
    [art] => 3
    [mystery] => 1
)
```

Now I would like to turn that sorted array into a "regular" array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => [photo]
    [1] => [photography] 
    [2] => [art] 
    [3] => [mystery] 
)
```

How to do that?

Comment: array_keys() maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Comment: `$arr = array(
    "photo" => 9,
    "photography" => 6,
    "art" => 3,
    "mystery" => 1
   );
 
  $keys = array_keys($arr);
  print_r($keys);` This has been asked many times before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your first array is the variable $sortedArray, then you could do the following to get exactly what you want:

```
$regularArray = array_keys($sortedArray);
```

See the [array_keys php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) for more information.